# Convertir de String a Unsigned Char Array en C++

Tags: c++

Necesito convertir una cadena de caracteres string a unsigned char array de este modo:

```
string str_texto = "Hola Mundo!";
unsigned char uchar_texto[80];
```

Salida:

```
uchar_texto[0] = 0x68 //H
uchar_texto[1] = 0x6F //o
```

Hasta el momento he hecho esto y sirve bien una vez, el problema es que si la vuelvo a usar, la segunda vez deja de funcionar (no se porque pero no copia nada al unsigned char incluso renombrando todas las variables):

```
char *c_key1 = new char(16 + 1);

for(unsigned i = 0, unsigned_char_val; i < str_texto.length(); i += 2)
{
    sscanf(str_texto .c_str() + i, "%2X", &unsigned_char_val);
    c_key1[i/2] = unsigned_char_val;
    uchar_texto[i/2] = c_key1[i/2];
}
```

Tambien sé que esta esta otra forma de hacerlo pero si tuviera un string de 500 caracteres el código quedaría enorme:

```
sscanf(str_texto.c_str(), "%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX%02hhX...",
        &uchar_texto[0], &uchar_texto[1], &uchar_texto[2]...);
```

Por eso busco alguna forma que no sea estas dos para hacer esa conversión.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es todo muchísimo más sencillo de lo que estás haciendo. Pero antes de explicar mi propuesta vamos a corregir tus errores y fallos.

---

Para empezar has marcado la pregunta como [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) así que olvida la función `sscanf`, que pertenece a las rutinas de [c](/questions/tagged/c).

Después, en esta línea:

```
char *c_key1 = new char(16 + 1);
```

Crees que estás pidiendo memoria para 17 `char` cuando en realidad estás pidiendo memoria para un solo `char` cuyo valor es 17. Seguramente lo que querías hacer era:

```
char *c_key1 = new char[16 + 1];
//                     ^      ^ <--- corchetes, no paréntesis
```

#### Propuesta.

Para convertir una cadena de caracteres en una colección de valores `unsigned char` puedes:

Copiar los elementos "*a mano*":

```
std::string str_texto = "Hola Mundo!";
unsigned char uchar_texto[80]{};

for (int indice = 0; indice < str_texto.length(); ++indice)
    uchar_texto[indice] = static_cast<unsigned char>(str_texto[indice]);
```

O usar una función de copia:

```
std::string str_texto = "Hola Mundo!";
unsigned char uchar_texto[80]{};

std::copy(std::begin(str_texto), std::end(str_texto), std::begin(uchar_texto));
```

Comment: funcionó perfecto con el "for" y el "casteo" muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

```
unsigned char m_Test[20];

strcpy( static_cast <char*>( m_Test ), "Hello World" );
```

Utiliza este ejemplo obviamente si quieres puedes cambiar *Hello World* con tu variable **string**. Asegurate que el **char** tenga el tamaño adecuado o suficiente para almacenar la cadena por lo que te recomiendo cambiar `unsigned char m_Test[20];` en vez de 20 poner lo que necesitas.

Comment: Esto me da como resultado de la compilación "error: invalid static_cast from type 'unsigned char [96]' to type 'char*'"

Comment: Prueba esto: strcpy( (char*) m_Test, "Hello World" );

Comment: Es decir cambia la segunda linea